# Duplicate AICc values for multiple models with interactions

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, model-selection, aic

I am going through a model selection process with a mixed-model with 3 variables: A, B, and C. B and C are orthogonal factors. B or C may interact with A, so my full model would be:

fixed:

```
Y ~ A + B + C + A*B + A*C
```

random:

```
~1|D
```

When I run my analysis, I get four models sharing the lowest AICc.

```
Y ~ B + A*C
Y ~ A + B + A*C
Y ~ B + C + A*C
Y ~ A + B + C + A*C
```

I am very confused about what is going on. Obviously there is an interaction between A and C, but how can they all have the same AICc value? Where do I go from here in model selection?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently all these formulas are equivalent in R. No matter which model I run, the data summary includes parameters for A, B, C, and A*C. I guess if you have an interaction between A and C, then by default, A and C must be in the model. You learn something new everyday!

Comment: you can add an interaction term in R's lm() without the main effects through writing a:b